# Windows Home Group - share library

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, lan, shared-folders

I don't understand the following behavior of Windows 7 Home Premium:
We've set up a 'windows home-network-group" between multiple computers. On computer 1 we have a win7-library with 2 folders in it (Folder A and B, Folder A is checked as primary).
Now on PC 1 we do a right click on the library, share with home group, read only.

On computer 2, we can see computer 1 and ONE folder (in addition to the default share stuff). And this folder we can acces: B. But this makes no sense. If there is only one folder, it should be the primary folder of the libarry OR (what we wanted) BOTH folders.

Can anybody explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is go to the Control Panel, Network, HomeGroup.  Create / configure the HomeGroup
Take the time to investigate / create Libraries.